# Disabling TLS1 in Embedded Jetty running Spring Boot 1.2.5

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

Can't figure out how to set the excepted protocols for the connector. 
 Requirement to only allow TLSV1.1 and TLSV1.2 traffic.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer customizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                customizeJetty((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container);
            }
        }

        private void customizeJetty(JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory jetty) {
            jetty.addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

                @Override
                public void customize(Server server) {
                    for (Connector connector : server.getConnectors()) {
                        if (connector instanceof ServerConnector) {
                            HttpConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ((ServerConnector) connector)
                                    .getConnectionFactory(HttpConnectionFactory.class);
                            connectionFactory.getHttpConfiguration()
                                    .setRequestHeaderSize(16 * 1024);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Show how you created your `ServerConnector`s in the first place.  (Modifying the ServerConnectors in place is not the way to go here)

Comment: Actually I want to do the following but with jetty.